# How to have domain point to github pages?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, cname, github, 1and1

So I have a domain registered with 1&1 and I recently decided to create my website using GitHub pages. I added as GitHub told me to, but how can I make my domain point to my GitHub page?

Answer (score 1):

You can forward or redirect your domain.

**Redirect type**

301 (Permanent) — Redirects to the site you specified in the Forward To field using a "301 Moved Permanently" HTTP response. The HTTP 301 response code tells user-agents (including search engines) that the location has permanently moved.

302 (Temporary) — Redirects to the site you specified in the Forward To field using a "302 Found" HTTP response. The HTTP 302 response code tells user-agents (including search engines) that the location has temporarily moved.

**Forwarding**

Forward only — Forwards the domain without masking.

Forward with Masking — Prevents the forwarded domain name URL from displaying in the browser's address bar, and lets you enter Meta Tags for search engine crawlers in the following fields:

- Title — Displays at the top of the browser window and in search
  results. Description — A short description of your website to display
  in search engine results.
- Keyword — A list of comma-separated keywords that describes the
  content and purpose of your website.