# How to configure GoDaddy domain to point to a specific github pages repository?

Tags: dns, godaddy, github

We have a [github repository](https://github.com/nordible/nordible.github.io) which is configured to point to [nordible.com](http://nordible.com/):

[image]

Hitting [nordible.github.io](http://nordible.github.io) successfully lands to [nordible.com](http://nordible.com/).

> So, we've successfully connected a github website to a custom domain!

[image]

The domain [nordible.com](http://nordible.com/) is with [GoDaddy](https://godaddy.com).

Now, what steps shall we take at [GoDaddy](https://godaddy.com) side to make [nordible.com](http://nordible.com/) show the pages from [nordible.github.io](http://nordible.github.io)?

We noticed that, there are ways to [redirect a domain to a specific Github page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86875/51058). However, we need a direct non-redirecting way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want the canonical site to have **no** `www`.   [Github publishes step by step instructions for that case](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en).  If you do want the `www`, those instructions are [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-www-subdomain/).

It basically boils down to pointing the domain name to github's IP address.   You can set up an `A` record with `192.30.252.153` or `192.30.252.154`.

Instructions for adding an `A` record to GoDaddy's DNS can be found here: https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238

You can't use a CNAME without the `www` because it will break email for the domain.   MX records get ignored if there is a CNAME record at the apex.

I don't think that GoDaddy supports `ALIAS` records. Those are basically proxy records where you put in domain name to treat like a `CNAME`, but the DNS provider looks up the IP address, caches it for a few minutes, and serves it as an `A` record.   If you want to use an `ALIAS` record, you would have to switch to a DNS host that supports them such as [Amazon Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/).

Comment: But before adding any `A` record, do I need to remove the existing `A` record  with value set to `184.168.221.49`

Comment: If it is for the bare domain, or for `www` then "yes".   If it is for a different subdomain such as "webmail", you might want to leave it.

Comment: Damn, this is extreme! From now, you're my guru!